# jQuery selecting data value from fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across another issue with jquery. I seen code that uses .ajax() method and the response is being selected like this

```js
.then(response => {
  $(response).find('.some-selector')
})
```

This is really confusing me.

I did a refactor to vanilla js like this

```js
fetch('/some-endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(e.currentTarget)
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(data => {
  data.querySelector('.some-selector') // does not work
})
```

Everything is working, the response is good, but I do not understand how to get the selected value from the data.

Comment: The response in the jquery code is an html string and if you put that in jQuery it can also find elements in that string. This doesn't work in vanilla JS. You would have to parse the response to html first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the response first:

```js
fetch('/some-endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(e.currentTarget)
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(function(html) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  return parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
})
.then(data => {
  data.querySelector('.some-selector');
})
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick, thanks a lot!